# Creating a new user account using iCloud password

Tags: macos, icloud, apple-id, password, user-account

I am trying to create a new OS X user account using iCloud password but the option to do that isn't displayed.

I am on OS X 10.11.4
[image: Screenshot]

According to this [support document](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21986?locale=en_US) I should see an option to pick the kind of password and set the iCloud ID.

FileVault is turned off, so I can't think of a reason for this to be happening.

I also don't have the option to change the iCloud ID on my current account.

If I create the account I can't set the iCloud ID on it either.
Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Having the same issue as well. Recently changed my Apple ID and now I can't seem to switch to the iCloud password.

Comment: @stefanbc was that an issue before OS X 10.11.4?

Comment: No. I was able to do that before the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using steps 1-6 on this [website](https://www.maketecheasier.com/reset-os-x-account/).

Basically in single user mode in the terminal I ran:

`mount -uw
rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
shutdown -h`

I then set up the iMac using the other account I wanted to create.

While this isn't an ideal solution (and may bring some other issues?) it works until Apple fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The linked iCloud/OS X Password feature appears have been removed in 10.11.4

The Change Password Dialogue box used to ask if you wanted to link your iCloud password with your account, now it goes directly to "Old password/New Password"

[image: Change Password Dialogue]

Comment: Have they also removed the option to set an iCloud ID / Apple ID on a user account as well? I was talking to Apple Care and the senior advisor said that it should still be a feature in OS X 10.11.4 and that it was on her laptop.

For the account that I already had created it presented a dialog asking me to change my iCloud password when I clicked on reset password maybe because it was created pre OS X 10.11.4.

Comment: I just did a clean install and it let me use my iCloud account. However I still can't do it for a second account.

Comment: If you right click on a username you can go to Advanced settings. You can set an Apple ID there. But for some reason they removed the use iCloud password feature.

Comment: stefanbc is correct here.  If you want to add an iCloud account to a user just create the user and sign in to iCloud in iCloud settings. I believe this does the same thing as changing the iCloud account in Advanced settings

Comment: I found doing that didn't enable iCloud password.